# Using sed to replace multiple instances in the same line before a comment

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to use sed to replace all instances of a command with a variable, expect when they come after a comment or is part of another word. I have gotten close, being able to replace one instance before a comment, but not if there is more than one.

I have a test file with the line:
`rm rm # rm`

I want to make this read:
`$RM $RM # rm`

This is what I have so far:
`sed -i 's/\(^\|[^[#.*]]\)\brm\b/\1$RM/' file1`

Which returns:
`$RM rm # rm`

Any help is much appreciated. Other solutions not involving sed are welcome, but I might need some help understanding them.

Thanks!

EDIT:

This is just an example of what I am looking for. Not every line will be formatted like this, and not every line will contain a command before the comment, or vise versa. I am just looking for a solution that will also cover a situation similar to this example. Sorry for the lack of explanation. Here is a slightly better example:

```
   "$#"    #rm
#  rm
rm   #  rm
  rm
"rm  "
'rm  '
`rm  `
{rm  }
$#  rm  # rm
rm rm # rm
rm # rm rm
rmremovermlink
```

Output should be:

```
  "$#"    #rm
#  rm
$RM   #  rm
  $RM
"$RM  "
'$RM  '
`$RM  `
{$RM  }
$#  $RM  # rm
$RM $RM # rm
$RM # rm rm
rmremovermlink
```

Comment: What's your expected output for above input file?

Comment: No no, not in comments. Update the question with your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `perl` command for this substitution:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\$)#.*$(*SKIP)(*F)|\brm\b/\$RM/g' file
   "$#"    #rm
#  rm
$RM   #  rm
  $RM
"$RM  "
'$RM  '
`$RM  `
{$RM  }
$#  $RM  # rm
$RM $RM # rm
$RM # rm rm
rmremovermlink
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL5iD3/4)

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks for including the RegEx demo. That was really helpful for understanding why everything works the way it did.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this sed command:

```
sed ':a;s/^\([^#]*\)\<rm\>/\1$RM/;ta;' file
#    ^  ^   ^       ^   ^  ^      ^---- go to label "a" if something is replaced
#    |  |   |       |   |  '---- back-reference to capture group 1
#    |  |   |       '---'---- word boundaries
#    |  |   '---- capture group 1
#    |  '---- replacement (only one occurrence)
#    '---- defines the label "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\$[A-Z]{2}\s\$[A-Z]{2}\s\#\s[a-z]{2}
```

Let me know if this is what you're looking for. It matches :

```
$RM $RM # rm
```

Comment: So, I guess I wasn't too clear in my question. Sorry. I am looking for a way to replace the command without knowing where it could be. This answer works for this specific situation, but unfortunately I do not know how the lines will be formatted.

Comment: Can you provide couple of examples to be tests instead of that one in your question. Thanks.